# Prestashop installation homestead guide

Tags: vagrant, homestead, prestashop-1.7

So I had trouble while installing Prestashop 1.7 correctly and thought I would post my own guide to install it with Homestead (vagrant, virtualbox):

There we go:

Download prestashop

Have vagrant and homestead installed

Cd into your homestead folder and run vagrant - `vagrant up`

Extract ONLY THE FIRST zip in "...code\prestashop" folder

Configure homestead.yaml file by adding:

```
sites:
    - map: prestashop.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/prestashop
      php: "7.0"

databases:
    - prestashop
```

add     `192.168.10.10   prestashop.test` to your hosts file

run `vagrant provision`

Open "prestashop.test" (or whatever other name you put in the homestead.yaml file) in browser

Proceed with prestashop installation

Comment out (_install) or delete the install folder (otherwise you will get an error when trying to open prestashop in the browser)

```
vagrant ssh
```

In vagrant ssh `cd /etc/nginx/sites-available` and run `ls` to see if prestashop is present

```
sudo nano prestashop.test
```

Add this between root and index and change the admin name on BOTH lines to your generated unique one:

```
location /admin/ {
if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite ^/.*$ /admin/index.php last;
}
}
```

then `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload`

Open prestashop.test/admin() (in the brackets put your unique admin name (without the brackets) and voilà!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks , Todor!

Comment: Should have set it up as a question / answer post...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having to edit Nginx config file you can simply use Apache, all that you have to do is to specified apache as a site type:

```
sites:
    - map: prestashop.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/prestashop
      php: "7.0
      type: "apache"
```

It looks like there are some issues with Nginx that require to edit the config by hand just as @Todor did, more info here [Does PrestaShop 1.7 work with Nginx? - General topics - PrestaShop Forums](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/986401-does-prestashop-17-work-with-nginx/)

Answer (score 3):

In PS version: 1.7.6.7 i was forced to uncoment those two lines in `.htaccess` located in admin folder:

```
     RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
     RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Before that for links like: `http://presta17.shop/admin466vvxojo/improve/modules/manage?_token=ZrnM85TEsROusexXinPySyjZQghmfHO7d7sSFI3Tgm4`
with `/index.php/` i get only: `Access denied.`

Comment: it's a winner for me. Saved me a couple of hours, cheers.